# Добавление элемента Select Options JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Имеется ComboBox при выборе который передаёт полученные значения из базы при помощи ajax во второй ComboBox, когда приходит 1 значение все отображается корректно, но если приходят 2 значения они записываются в 1 строчку, а нужно что бы добавлял в следующий Options. Прошу вашей помощи

**Код**

```
var t = null;
$( "#hotelid" ).change(function() {
    t = $( "#hotelid :selected" );
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: './modules/common.php',
    data: { fn: 'combobox', id: t.val() },
    dataType: 'json',
  }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var list = data.list.rooms;
        var e =""; 
        for (var i = 0; i < data.list.length; i++) {
        e += data.list[i].rooms;

        $( "#roomid option:selected").text(e);
        $( "#roomid option:selected").val(e);           

};

});
});
```

**UP**

Ответ ajax

```
{list: [{rooms: "Еще комната"}, {rooms: "тест на кол-во"}]}

Эти 2 значения должны попасть в `<option value="value"></option>` сейчас пока только 1 показывает.
```

**html**

```
<select type="text" class="form-control" name="roomid" id="roomid"> 
                    <option value="value"></option>
                </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$( "#hotelid" ).change(function() {
  // simulate asynchronous ajax
  var response = {list: [{rooms: "Еще комната"}, {rooms: "тест на кол-во"}]};
  setTimeout(function(data) {
    var room = $( "#roomid option:selected");
    for (var i = 0; i < data.list.length; i++) {
      e = data.list[i].rooms;
      
      if (room.length == 0) {
        $("#roomid").append("<option></option>");
        room = $("#roomid option").last();
      }
      room.text(e);
      room.val(e);

      room = room.next(); 
    }
  }, 1000, response);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select type="text" class="form-control" name="hotelid" id="hotelid"> 
  <option value="value1">Royal</option>
  <option value="value2">Savoy</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select type="text" class="form-control" name="roomid" id="roomid"> 
  <option value="value"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, но проблема осталась... теперь он показывает 1 значение хотя пришло 2.

Comment: кто это - "он"?

Comment: Сам в шоке, вот результат из базы.
id
rooms
2
Еще комната
5
тест на кол-во
результат <option value="Еще комната">Еще комната</option>

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в Ваш вопрос имеющий отношение к делу html и образец ответа на ajax запрос, с указанием, куда и что должно попадать.

Comment: добавил как Вы и просили.

Comment: Спасибо тебе добрый человек, дай бог тебе здоровья